# How to update Row/column value in a Apache Spark DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an ordered Spark `DataFrame`and I would like to change a few rows while iterating it using the following code but it seems there is not any way to update Row object.

```
orderedDataFrame.foreach(new Function1<Row,BoxedUnit>(){

@Override
public BoxedUnit apply(Row v1) {
// How do I change Row here? 
// I want to change column no 2 using v1.get(2)
// also what is BoxedUnit, and how do I use it
return null;
}
});
```

Also above code is giving compilation error saying:

> myclassname is not abstract and it does not override abstract method apply$mcVj$sp(long) in scala Function 1

I am new to Spark. I am using 1.4.0 release.

Comment: Could you provide some context? A whole idea of updating rows inside `foreach` smells fishy but mostly likely there are other ways to approach the problem. BTW Are you interested only in Java specific solutions? If so a [tag:java] tag or some comment could be useful.

Comment: Hi yes reason behind updating rows in foreach is my data set have one field process id and corresponding process count field within that process time span so I would like to order by each rows in process id bases and want to update few other process level fields serially. It's weird use case I accept.

Comment: OK, IMHO it is definitely not a way to go. There are multiple possible problems starting with a notion of data immutability which is as far I understand quite fundamental for Spark internals, through what is actually going on when you apply transformations and perform actions, and ending with performance and correctness. You may map over grouped data frame, use SQL with window functions, subset, map and union. There is a good reason why Row doesn't allow items assignment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try This:

```
 final DataFrame withoutCurrency = sqlContext.createDataFrame(somedf.javaRDD().map(row -> {
            return RowFactory.create(row.get(0), row.get(1), someMethod(row.get(2)));
        }), somedf.schema());
```

Comment: Good solution, I was struggling with how to append new rows to a `DataFrame` of modified existing rows. This provides a convenient way to get a new data frame then use `.unionAll` with the existing `DataFrame`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dataset<Row> ds = spark.createDataFrame(Collections.singletonList(data), SellerAsinAttribute.class);
        ds.map((i)-> {
            Object arrayObj = Array.newInstance(Object.class, i.length());
            for (int n = 0; n < i.length(); ++n) {
                Array.set(arrayObj, n, i.get(n));//change 'i.get(n)' to anything you want, if you change type, remember to update schema
            }
            Method create = RowFactory.class.getMethod("create", Object[].class);
            return (Row) create.invoke(null, arrayObj);
        }, RowEncoder.apply(ds.schema())).show();
```

Comment: Spark 2.3 tested